# Converting datetime to date in ADF Mapping?

Tags: mapping, azure-data-factory

I have a requirement for the final output text delimited document to contain only dates, however the json which I am reading as the Source in my ADF Copy Activity has the datetime fields as  "hireDate": "1988-03-28T00:00:00+00:00", for example; I need these to be "1988-03-28". Any suggestions on doing this in the ADF Mapping (and we don't have Data Flow Mapping in the government Azure Cloud).
Thank you
Mike Kiser

Comment: Can you consider copying to the Azure SQL table first? Then copying to the txt file.

Comment: Synapse workspaces have dataflows in gov cloud

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No choice, we need an intermediate process, eg: We can copy the json file into a Azure SQL table, then copy from Azure SQL into a txt file.

1. Create a table and set the column type to `date`.

```sql
create table dbo.data1(
    hireDate date
)
```

2. Copy into the table. It automatically casts the type from `datetime` to `date` .
   [image]
3. The debug result is as follows:
   [image]